# C# DateTime calculation and ToString

Tags: c#, datetime

Im doing simple calculation with time, to see how long the process has been running.

```
(DateTime.Now - StrtTime).ToString("hh:mm:ss")
```

Where StrtTime is:`DateTime StrtTime = DateTime.Now;`
. But im getting an exception:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: I believe you should use a `Stopwatch`

Comment: (DateTime.Now - StrtTime) should be returning TimeSpan if StrtTime is DateTime too. I am afraid you provided the wrong code.

Comment: In order to avoid DateTime arithmetic, have you seen `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`? Using DateTime.Now is quite expensive and possibly inaccurate because it requires time zone info from OS. What would happen if your run occurred when the clocks change to/from daylight saving? At the very least, consider using `DateTime.UtcNow`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One `DateTime` subtracting another results in a `TimeSpan` value, not another `DateTime`. The `TimeSpan` does not support your given format string.

For standard `TimeSpan` format strings, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for custom formats.

However, to measure the process time, you *should* instead use a tool better equipped for the task, `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

DoSomeProcess();

watch.Stop();
TimeSpan processTime = watch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: Ok, thnx. Using stopwatch now like this: `String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Elapsed.Hours, ts.Elapsed.Minutes, ts.Elapsed.Seconds` where `ts` is `Stopwatch ts = new Stopwatch();`

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned you may want to use `StopWatch`.  However in your particular case you are getting an error because you need to escape ":" when using a formatting string with `TimeSpan.ToString`.  Try this:

```
(DateTime.Now - StrtTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")
```

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: It may be a better solution to use StopWatch but the OP is getting an error.  I am just explaining why he is getting this error.  The formatting string I gave is supported by TimeSpan.  Try it yourself before downvoting.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the custom timespan format section on msdn :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Stopwatch stpWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
            stpWatch1.Start();
            .............
            stpWatch1.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stpWatch1.Elapsed;// it also contains stpWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

As Anthony mentioned, Stopwatch would be better suited for this task. To answer your question though, you can format the Date like this:

```
String.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", (DateTime.Now - StrtTime).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stopwatch class.

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        //code

        sw.Stop();

        sw.Elapsed.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

As Anthony said, the subtraction results in a `TimeSpan`.

`TimeSpan` accepts a different format:

[TimeSpan.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx)